# CSS Flex Section Background Color

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have built a product landing page using Flex. I have a section which I have given an id="hero". Right now, the background color (#e0bdfc) extends to the full width of the browser window. However, I would like to have it cut off at around 1000px (which is the same as my container max-width and my footer). When I tried using max-width: 1000px;, nothing happened. I'm not sure why. I wonder if something else in my entire CSS is affecting it. Maybe not. Below is my CSS snippet for #hero.

```
#hero {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #e0bdfc;
    
}
```

If you need to view my full html and css files, you can view them on Github [here](https://github.com/heathology/product-landing-page).

You can view the live site [here](https://heathology.github.io/product-landing-page/) to see my code in context.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't wrap this part of the hero part in container, so the width of that part doesn't follow the container,try to wrap the hero part first.I hope this helps

```html
<div class="container"></div>
        <section id="hero">
            <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
            <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" data-dashlane-rid="8ad77776c40e5c69"
                data-form-type="register,step">
                <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required=""
                    data-form-type="email">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Get Started" class="btn" data-form-type="action,next">
            </form>
        </section>
```

[here this your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVeKq.jpg)

Comment: Ah! Such a simple mistake! Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `max-width` didn't work for you, but it did for me in the inspector tool. I also centered the element by setting `margin` left and right to `auto` while keeping your top margin. Hopefully this helps! [image]

```
#hero {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    background-color: #e0bdfc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also try to add max-width: 1000px and margin: 0 auto to center the block and then it worked.

You can try to add this code:

```
#hero {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #e0bdfc;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1000px;
```

}

This is the result:
[image]